# What is the best way to move a touring motor glider over a wet grass surface?

Tags: taxiing, non-towered-airport, taxiways

In a flight club we operate an SF-25C (about 480kg empty).

In fall and winter the surface (grass) of our taxiways often gets to wet so if we would move the aircraft we would damage the field and we get insulted by the glider guys for ruining their season. However the runways itself (once reached) is fine all year.

Preparing the airfield itself is not possible because of environmental reasons and because we only rented the field and because the distance we need to travel is about 1km many of the options regarding the airfield are out.

The question is, does anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem? Are there any existing solutions? A special trailer, rc tracked platforms..

Here is a picture of that aircraft (to see the landing gear):

[image]
<sup>source: https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/8664499</sup>

Comment: This sounds really dumb, but can't you taxi it there? I presume it lives in a hangar with a hard floor -- in my experience pushing aircraft on wet grass often results in slipping tyres on the grass (and damaged grass as a result) whereas if the aircraft is moving under its own power the wheels *tend* to rotate.

Comment: I think his problem is the taxiway gets so soft that the very small tires on the Falke make deep ruts while rolling.  Balloon tires would be the easiest solution but it would require an oversize nose gear fork, and so much for motorgliding with the drag of big tires.

Comment: How far does it need to be moved?  Is there a straight path to the hard surface?

Comment: @Jim Worst case about 1km streight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that as a motorglider the Falke has very small tires, 5.00 x 5 or even smaller.  The "on-board" fix would be to install much larger tires to increase the contact patch area, but that would require a new nose gear fork and really big fairings if you still wanted to preserve some L/D, if you could even acquire the parts.

About the only other solution would be a special towing rig where you pull the plane onto a custom-made low slung platform trailer with large balloon tires and tow it behind an ATV or similar, also with high flotation tires, to a spot where the ground is firm enough.